# R PCA plot using Hotelling's T2 for a confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval, pca

For my test data, I calculated the first two principal components using the `prcomp` function. I then plotted the first 2 components using the plot function.

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = runif(10), x2 = runif(10), x3 = runif(10), x4 = runif(10))
rownames(df) <- letters[1:10]

res <- prcomp(df, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)

plot(res$x, xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-5, 5))
```

I now would like to place an ellipse around the data that represens a 95% confidence interval using Hotelling's T2 statistic.

The `SensoMineR` package in particular the `panellipse` function seems to be what I am looking for. However, my R knowledge is still quite limited and I was therefore wondering if you could point me in the right direction on to construct such a confidence interval.

Many thanks!
Jacky

Comment: I just installed the pcaMethods package which includes a function simpleEllipse which simply does what it says. You can pass the first two PCA components to it and it - as far as I understood - returns the coordinates for the corresponding 95% conf interval ellipse. However, the problem is that when I type in the function in R it says:
Error: object 'simpleEllipse' not found. However, typing ?simpleEllipse opens the help page for that function. I don't understand that. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

SensoMineR is good.

There is another package called [Package ‘Hotelling’](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hotelling/Hotelling.pdf) which is easy to  place an ellipse around the data.

[Package ‘Hotelling’](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hotelling/Hotelling.pdf)